# How to join without losing special characters?

Tags: tcl, special-characters

I have the following string:

```
"name\r {} {} {} {} {} other_name other_name {} {} -600.0 {} {} 860.0 {} {} -"
```

(i.e. string with the special character: \r ).

When I `join` this line then I lose the special charecters.

Suppose:

```
set name "name\r {} {} {} {} {} other_name other_name {} {} -600.0 {} {} 860.0 {} {} -"

set name [join $name]
```

Now the name is losing the special characters(at least `\r`).

How to resolve this?

Comment: Does your `$name` variable even keep `name\r`? I can't even make it do that on my machine...?

Comment: Actually the name variable is not initialized as I do. It's the output of another operation, And when I print it and its look like: "name\r {} {} {} {} {} other_name other_name {} {} -600.0 {} {} 860.0 {} {} -".

Comment: Ah, okay, try to see if my answer below solves your problem ^^

Comment: How do you get such a thing? Do you concat a list and a string?

Comment: You shouldn't get such a "list" in the first place. If the proc that returns that string is supposed to return a valid list string, the problem is in that proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things and came up with this:

```
set name {name\r {} {} {} {} {} other_name other_name {} {} -600.0 {} {} 860.0 {} {} -}
# The braces prevent the substitution of \r

regsub -all {\\r} $name {\\\r} name
# This is a substitution using regexp to substitute all \r to \\r

set name [join $name]
# Returns: "name\r      other_name other_name   -600.0   860.0   -"
```

Or in case there might be more characters you might want to escape, use the more general:

```
regsub -all {\\} $name {\\\\} name
```

instead.

Comment: By the way, by 'more characters', I mean if you also have `\t` or `\n` and similar special characters. The switch `-all` already substitutes all the occurrences of `\r` to `\\r`.